# Magento Remove an items from Quote Items, Order total not updated

Tags: magento

Trying to remove an item from the quote object, but cannot get order total updated.

For example, a customer adds product A ($2), and B ($3) to the cart, and then place the order.

After customer hits the place order button, I am trying to remove product B from the order.

Using the code below, I can successfully remove B from the order. But the total of the order is not updated.

```
$quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
```

Say I have product B removed, then order should have a total of $2, but I checked from the order grid in backend, the total was $5.

Answer (score 0):

//Try with the below code. not tested.

```
$quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
$quote->save();
```

//I thing you need to remove items from order to reflect your changes in order.

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->isDeleted(true);
}
```

Please note that this is not recommended to do things like this as per this link [More details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15966/how-to-delete-order-item-from-order-object)

Comment: @Jewel If you find this answer useful then please upvote, So it will helpful for other community user.